# Using reference in fetch_field

Tags: php, reference

I have this example

```
 function read()
{
   $parameters = array();
   $results = array();

   $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'test') or die('There was a problem connecting to the database');
   $stmt = $mysql->prepare('SELECT id,body,posts FROM post') or die('Problem preparing query');
   $stmt->execute();

   $meta = $stmt->result_metadata(); 

   while ( $field = $meta->fetch_field() ) {

     $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];

   }

   call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);

   while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
      $x = array();

      foreach( $row as $key => $val ) {

         $x[$key] = $val;
      }
      $results[] = $x;
   }

   return $results;
}

$results = read();
```

And I cogitate why I need reference in this example `$parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];`
It doesn't work without **&** . I found this example in [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/the-problem-with-phps-prepared-statements/). Could you explain me why need using reference and from var $row come from. Is it a part of fetch_field?

Answer (score 0):

```
$parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
```

means `$parameters[]` is now referencing `$row[$field->name]` i.e `$parameters[]` is now pointing at the value of `$row[$field->name]` which means any change in `$row[$field->name]` will also reflect in  `$parameters[]`

See this example to get things better !

```
<?php
$foo = 'Hello';
$bar = 'World'; 
print $foo . " " . $bar;// Hello World

$foo = &$bar;
$bar = 'Hello My World';

print $foo;// Hello My World
print $bar;// Hello My World

?>
```

hope this helps !